# How can I get access to my Symfony app on my server?

Tags: apache, symfony, server

I cloned my Symfony app to my server and when I want to open the website I get the error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache Server at mywebsite.com Port 80

What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to link my domain to the public folder instead of the root folder

Answer (score 1):

1. I would check the owner of the files in terminal.
2. I would check vhost file, on my local Ubuntu the location is /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Comment: I found out that the website was linked to the root. Instead it had to be linked to the public folder

Answer (score 1):

You could check if you didn't miss any important step from the webserver configuration documentation
[Configuring a Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

like installing the **apache Symfony pack** or manually set an .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna need more information about the system. Which symfony version do you have? Have you seen the loggers? Have you deployed the system on a docker container? Which version of PHP are you using? Maybe you are missing some dependencies.